# How do you disable copy paste within an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am using google viewer api and I want to disable the copy paste functionality within the frame.

example:

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://infolab.stanford.edu/pub/papers/google.pdf&embedded=true" style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: Do you control the `iframe` src? I am guessing no because it is hosted by google

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to. One idea I'm thinking of is overlaying a transparent div on the iframe so you can't interact with it at all... but I'm not even sure that'll work.

Comment: Hi, How would i be able to use the div trick?

Comment: Hi I do not own the source of the iframe it is google. Thanks

Comment: You can't stop a determined user from copying from a web page, though you can make it more difficult. Why do you want to disable it?

Comment: Note that it's generally considered poor form to mess with the browser chrome, including default right click actions.

Comment: Hi, I understand a determined user will be able to get access. It is to provide a minor roadblock for non technical users. Is there a way to make it more difficult for iframes?

Comment: @sachleen that would work, apparently, as long as div and iFrame have absolute position and correct z-index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution (from my comment):

> One idea I'm thinking of is overlaying a transparent div on the iframe so you can't interact with it at all.

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/iqitux/1/)

HTML

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="overlay">
  </div>
  <iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://infolab.stanford.edu/pub/papers/google.pdf&embedded=true" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#overlay {
  width:590px;
  height:500px;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color:rgba(255,255,0,0.1);
}
iframe {
  width:600px;
  height:500px;

}
#container {
  position: relative;
}
#overlay, iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

I made the overlay (yellow box) width 590px so you still have 10px for the scrollbar.

Comment: That'll make it impossible to interact with the iframe **at all**, though -- you won't even be able to scroll it, making it pretty unusable.

Comment: I know. I acknowledged that. You could change the size of the overlay to allow you to interact with the controls but not the document, like what I did for the scrollbar.

Comment: Hi Thank you Sachleen! This is very useful. How would I go upon making it scrollable though (while preventing copy/paste)? Would I use JS? This is a very good solution. Thank you so much.

Comment: It's already scrollable. Not mouse wheel scrollable, but scroll bar scrollable. I don't know how to send the mouse wheel from the overlay div to the iframe.

Comment: Thank you again. One small question. How could I move the box down so the tool bar elements (zoom, page) can be clicked? Would this involve CSS or JS. Thank you so much